# Rails grouping object by indexing order in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, filtering, grouping

I get the list of words from DB and ordered using

```
@notes_list_title_asc = current_user.notes.order(:title)
```

This is how i am listing the words

```
<% @notes_list.each do |note| %>
            <li>
              <span class="title"><%= link_to note.title, edit_note_path(note) %></span>
              <span class="updated"><%= time_ago_in_words(note.updated_at).gsub('about','') + ' ago'  %></span>
            </li>
        <% end %>
```

I want to order my list of words like dictionary with A as title for words like Article and B for Brother.

And yes there is a way. But i don't know how. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [group_by](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/group_by) first letter of each word.

```
current_user.notes.order(:title).group_by { |note| note.title[0] }
```

So in your controller:

```
@notes = current_user.notes.order(:title).group_by { |note| note.title[0] }
```

And in your view:

```
- @notes.each do |letter, notes|
  %h3= letter
  %ul
    - notes.each do |note|
      %li
       %span.title= link_to note.title, edit_note_path(note)
       %span.updated= time_ago_in_words(note.updated_at).gsub('about', '') + ' ago'
```

**Edit:**

`order(:title)` ordering your notes in alphabetically order. `group_by` collect an enumerable into sets, grouped by the result of a block ([source](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/group_by)).

So, the block returns the first letter of note's title. So, your notes are grouped by the first letter of note's title.
You receive a hash: `{ "A" => [Note1, Note2], "B" => [Note3] }`.

In your view, you itinerates through the hash. For each letter, you have an array of notes. Then you itinerates that array of notes to display each note.

In order to have the first letter of a string: `"example"[0]` give you `"e"`.

Comment: Thanks Florent Ferry. That works like a magic. But can u explain what happens in the background scene as i m a newbie for rails and Thanks again. :)